# Show that if $x - r$ divides $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, then $r \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus

> Let $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ where $f$ is monic. If $x-r$ divides $f(x)$, show that $r \in \mathbb{Z}$.

This is my homework question. I feel like it's possible for $r$ to be a rational, because a polynomial with integer coefficients can have rational roots. So I'm a bit confused. Can somebody give me a solid explanation please?

Comment: By 'divides' you mean that $f(x)/(x-r)\in\Bbb{Z}[x]$, right? I'm not great with abstract algebra terminology.

Comment: I guess, $f$ is assumed to be *monic*, i.e. its leading coefficient should be $1$. Else e.g. $x-\frac12\, |\, 2x-1$ is a counterexample.

Comment: I guess you should also assume $r \in \mathbb{Q}$ - otherwise, for example, $x - \sqrt{2} \mid x^2 - 2$, and $x - i \mid x^2 + 1$.

Comment: Yes, $f$ is supposed to be monic, oops.

Comment: For people still stuck on this, [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1927806/let-fx-xn-a-n-1xn-1-cdots-a-0-in-bbb-zx-and-r-in-bbb-q) has a solution.

Answer (score 2):

> I feel like it's possible for $r$ to be a rational, because a polynomial with integer coefficients can have rational roots.

Yes, you're right. The statement is false. For clearly, for example, $$(x-1)(2x-1)$$ belongs in your ring and has the factor $(x-1/2).$

Comment: Right. I forgot to say that the leading coefficient of $f$ is $1$, so that $f$ is monic.

Comment: @MathematicalMushroom Is $r$ rational? Otherwise the statement would still be false, as $x^2\pm2$ belong to your ring and are monic, and can be factored over $C$ and $R$ respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $r=\frac{q}{p}$ is rational and f is monic and $f(x)=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_1 x+a_0$
so we have $0=p^{n-1} f(r) = \frac{q^n}{p}+a_{n-1} q^{n-1}+a_{n-2}q^{n-2}p+...+a_1 qp^{n-2}+a_0 p^{n-1}=0$
So fraction $\frac{q^n}{p}$ should be equal to integer $-(a_{n-1} q^{n-1}+a_{n-2}q^{n-2}p+...+a_1 qp^{n-2}+a_0 p^{n-1})$ which means $p=1$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  This follows from [Gauß's lemma](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomial)#The_lemma_over_the_integers)  (if we assume $r\in\Bbb Q$).